# automating sass compiling in windows

Tags: ruby, windows, automation, sass

So to put as simple as possible, I would like to incorporate SASS into a site I'm developing (the Internet seems to suggest SASS is the best pre-processor candidate) but I'm the type of developer that is always slightly tweaking CSS as I develop both back-end and front-end at same time. I can't afford a Mac or to build a linux box right now, and dealing with VMWare kinda sucks. So does anyone have a suggestion for how to create an automated process in the Windows env where when I save a SASS .scss file, it is automatically processed by the ruby sass and the css is file is generated and put in the correct project folder?

Comment: If I use something like aptana, can i automate the process in the IDE?

Comment: Is it a rails project? Developing rails apps on windows is a nightmare.

Comment: actaully django. bitnami has made it pretty easy for a small-time MVC site on windows, but basic shell scripting is always far away in some oversized gui app.

Comment: Have you tried VirtualBox?  I've been using it for a few years now and I think it works pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a tool like [Scout](http://www.impressivewebs.com/sass-on-windows-with-scout-app/)?

Comment: Perfect, exactly the type of solution I needed for being stuck in a Win box right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Prepros App](http://alphapixels.com/prepros) for windows. It can compile less, sass, scss, stylus, jade, haml and It can also live refresh your browser.

Btw, It's free and open source.